# Can EF6 use an existing table with GUIDs as the join/bridge table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, associations, entity-framework-6.1

I have an existing database and one of the tables for the existing webforms application is a join or bridge table called `PostCategory` that links up Posts and Categories but it uses GUIDs to do that. It has GUIDs for `CategoryID` and `PostID`. When I tried use fluent mapping to point EF at that table I got the error that only ints can be used.

So I suspect the answer is no but I wanted to ask in case someone has done it. [According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926288/cannot-get-the-entity-framework-to-handle-a-guid-relationship), it is possible with NHibernate but not EF.

> This is not possible with EF because it doesn't support unique keys. Only primary keys can be used as principal in relation.

Now the post is from 2012 so I though maybe something has changed with EF6.

Comment: It sounds like your Guid fields in your Post and Category tables are not configured as primary keys in your database. This has nothing to do with the datatype of the field. Guids are used as primary keys quite commonly.

Comment: No they are not set a primary keys. When the database was set up, that table had a key set on the column PostCategoryID. Currently as a workaround, I have had to create another bridge table in sql and point EF at that table which uses ints. The Post and Catgeory tables have keys set to PostRowID and CategoryRowID.